# "GET" multiple xml file in html

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I am trying to show multiple xml file into html. I able get single xml file show in html table by using **xmlhttp.open("GET", "204S_2000_02_17_00_30_357.xml", true)**. However, I can't get multiple xml file using this function.

I had tried using **xmlhttp.open("GET", "*.xml", true)** but doesn't get any output.

It's any solution or method to "GET" the multiple xml file into html?

**Noted:** xml file will continuously generate in folder with random name.(example 204S_2000_02_XX_XX_XX_XX.xml).

code that show single xml file in html table

```
function loadXMLDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      myFunction(this);
    }
  };
  xmlhttp.open("GET", "204S_2000_02_17_00_30_357.xml", true);
  xmlhttp.send();
}

function myFunction(xml) {
//coding....
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One HTTP request gets one HTTP response.

**In general**, you can't get multiple files back from a single request using a wildcard.

You could, **if you wrote suitable server-side code**, have the server recognise a wildcard in the URL and respond by (for example) sending a zip file containing all the files that matched, or generating a new XML document containing the contents of all the files that matched.

Generally, however, you will make a separate request for each resource you want. Having determined all the URLs you wanted to request, you would probably want to use an API that supported promises (i.e. `fetch` instead of `XMLHttpRequest`) so you could feed them into `Promise.all` and run the next stage of the program once you had collected all the data.

Comment: Any recommend tutorial or documentation to refer?